# Textarea doesn't render newline from DB

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have two `<textarea>` elements on a web page. When a user submits text in the *first* `<textarea>`, the text is inserted into a database. The text is then retrieved from the database and stored in the *second* `<textarea>` using Javascript.

The second textarea doesn't render the text if the characters from database contains newline characters.

If I type a word without newline, everything works great:

[image]

But the following one doesn't work.

[image]

**The `var_dump($output)`**  for

```
    n
    e
    w
    l
    i
    n
    e
```

**is**

```
string(19) "n e w l i n e"
```

My Code:

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="get">
  <textarea name="input" rows="5"></textarea> <br>
  <input type="submit" name="go"><br>
  <textarea name="output" id="id_ouput" rows="5"></textarea>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
...
...
$input=$_GET['input'];

$insert = $koneksi->query("insert into data values ('".$input."')");
$select = $koneksi->query("SELECT * FROM data"); // data is column
foreach ($select as $tampung){
    $output = $tampung['text'];
}

// use JS to access <textarea>' value attribute
?>
     <script>
         document.getElementById('id_ouput').value= "<?php echo $output ?>";
     </script>
<?php

...

?>
```

Comment: Try enclosing the textbox in `<pre>...</pre>` tags

Comment: what is the actual string? try doing `echo htmlentities($output);`

Comment: @SaumilSoni, it doesn't work also.

Comment: @twentylemon `<?php echo htmlentities($output); ?>` also doesn't work

Comment: It wasn't meant to just work, it was meant to debug. What is `$output`, raw?

Comment: @twentylemon, look at the first picture, it works fine, but the second one is not working because it contains newline, help me !

Comment: have you checked the encoding of your code files and the encoding of the database table and connection?

Comment: @AbcAeffchen, my html is `<meta charset="UTF-8">`

Comment: check if your file is really utf8 encoded, and your database connection should also use the utf8 encoding. I'm not sure if it is utf8 encoded by default. Maybe you have to make a query with `SET NAMES utf8` to activate the utf8 encoding.

Comment: Also: Why you use javascript to put text from your database via php into a html form? Why not just `<textarea ...><?php=$output ?></textarea>

Comment: I cannot see what problems your code has on the image. If you have problems when you use line breaks or maybe other characters like `ä`, it looks like an encoding problem. But I cannot track it down for you.

Comment: @AbcAeffchen, look at the first image everything is fine without newline, in my database file there is `/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;` information

Comment: We don't know the raw value of `$output`, it is clearly not `"n e w l i n e"`. There are no problems adding new lines `\n` in a `textarea`. So the problem is somewhere else. Did you look at the value by inspecting the element in HTML after it was assigned?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek, you're right but I didn't lie to you it's the ouput!! the problem is explained at below answer. Thank you and  all , I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your PHP code is outputting a malformed JavaScript string literal.

According to [ECMA-262](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMA-262), a double quoted string literal can contain any source character, except the **double quote** (`"`), **backslash** (`\`) and ***LineTerminator*** characters, where a *LineTerminator* is one of

- `\u000A` (Line Feed)
- `\u000D` (Carriage Return)
- `\u2028` (Line separator)
- `\u2029` (Paragraph separator)

You need to convert those characters into suitable JavaScript escape sequences, and you will also have to convert the `<` and `&` characters that have special meaning in an HTML document.

Most of the characters are simple ASCII characters which makes them trivial to replace using [`strtr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) with a translation table, assuming that your HTML document is using a reasonable (ASCII-compatible) character encoding.

The Line and Paragraph separators are trickier because the translation will depend on what character encoding your HTML document is using. If you're using UTF-8, those characters can be added to the translation table as follows:

```
<?php

  $conversion = array (
    '<'            => '&lt;',
    '&'            => '&amp;',
    '"'            => '\\"',
    '\\'           => '\\\\',
    "\r"           => '\\r',
    "\n"           => '\\n',
    "\xe2\x80\xa8" => '\\u2028',
    "\xe2\x80\xa9" => '\\u2029',
  );

  $output = $tampung['text'];
  $value = strtr ($output, $conversion);

  echo <<<_
<script>
     document.getElementById('id_ouput').value="$value";
</script>
_;
```

The PHP [`addcslashes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addcslashes.php) documentation has similar solutions in the comments section.

---

Of course, a much simpler solution would be to output the `<textarea>` value directly from PHP:

```
<?php

  $output = $tampung['text'];
  $value = htmlspecialchars ($output);

  echo <<<_
    <textarea name="output" id="id_ouput" rows="5">$value</textarea>

_;
```

But I'm guessing that your situation might be a little more complicated.

Comment: DUDE YOU ARE GENIUS!!! , most of the previous readers here didn't realize about it and they think that it  would just working fine.

Comment: @febri23: I'm happy it worked for you. It _looks_ like four people voted on your post without understanding the topic, although I think your question could merit from some clarification.